# How to display an error message when selecting a row that is in a different section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Essentially I have a tableView that is separated by sections.

The tableView allows for multiple row selections and displays an accessory .checkmark on all selected rows.

If the user begins to select rows under one section and try to select a different row under a different I would like for an alert message to appear and the selection not be made.

The following is the code so far:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var Name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")!
    var sections = [Section]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        fetchJSON()

        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        }

    }
```

Comment: dont post full code just related code man. you could have a bool value in your seccion array to check where is section[section] are all true

Comment: I am a bit unfamiliar with how to do this, can you please show me?

Comment: post your section model code

Comment: @kjoe Please see my update

Comment: @kjoe Are you there?

Comment: i'll see i got to gou out in a while i make a answer

Comment: Implement `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`. Inside it, retrieve the selected cells with `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. Retrieve all the sections of theses indexPaths. Check if the one that will be selected is the same. If not, show an alert, return nil to avoid the selection. If it is, return the indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`.

Use **`map(_:)`** to get the `sections` from `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

Check if the `indexPath's` `section` in `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)` is contained in the previously obtained `sections` `array` using **`contains(_:)`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let sections = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map({ $0.section }) {
        if !sections.contains(indexPath.section) {
            //Show Alert here....
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert..!!", message: "You're selection row from Section:\(indexPath.section)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return nil
        }
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

> **tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)** return value : An index-path object
>   that confirms or alters the selected row. Return an NSIndexPath object
>   other than indexPath if you want another cell to be selected. Return
>   nil if you don't want the row selected.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can do the following:

1. Add a bool value on your section struct to check if you have any item selected

```swift
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var hasItemsSelected: Bool
    let items : [Portfolios]
}
```

2. change your `didSelectRowAt`

```swift
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //when you select a row check if there is another row selected on another section by checking if the hasItemsSelected is true on all other sections

        //1. create an array containing all section besides the current section
        let allOtherSections = sections
                                    .enumerated()
                                    .filter {  $0.offset != indexPath.section }
                                    .map { $0.element } 

        //2. if allOtherSections does not have seledcted items
        if allOtherSections.allSatisfy { $0.hasItemsSelected == false } {
           self.sections[indexPath.section].hasItemsSelected = true
           tableView.cellForRow(at: ind exPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {

           let numberOfSelectedRowsOnCurrentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.enumerated().filter { $0.offset != 1 }.count
           if numberOfSelectedRowsOnCurrentIndexPath == 0 {
             self.sections[indexPath.section].hasItemsSelected = false
           }

           tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

           //show the alert here
           let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
           alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I hope I have helped you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614943-tableview). You can return nil from this delegate method to prevent a row from being selected.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let
        indexPathsForSelectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, indexPathsForSelectedRows.count > 0,
        indexPath.section != indexPathsForSelectedRows[0].section
    {
        // If there is at least one row already selected
        // And the section of that row is different than the section of the row about to be selected
        // Don't allow the selection
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: "Don't do that!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return nil
    }

    // There's either nothing selected yet or the section of this row is the same as those already selected
    return indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to create an extra logic for it, per example. 
You can put in one array all the indexPath you selected, and compare always the first item(indexPath) with each item you will go to add, the indexPath contains the property Section so just need to compare if the section are equals or not, if it isn't, you show de alert you want, after that you deselect the item manually.

```
var selectedItems = [IndexPath]()
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let firstIndexPath = selectedItems.first{
        //If the section with the first element selected and the new selection are not equals, display your message
        if indexPath.section != firstIndexPath.section{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {
                a in
                self.selectIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, isSelected: false)
            }))
            //You can put it here if you prefer not wait for the closure for realize the deselection
            //self.selectIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, isSelected: false)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        self.selectIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, isSelected: true)
    }else{
        self.selectIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath, isSelected: true)
    }


}
func selectIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath, isSelected: Bool){

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    if isSelected{
       selectedItems.append(indexPath)
    }else{
        selectedItems.removeAll(where: {$0 == indexPath})
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
    // for all selected rows assuming tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}
```